# How to solve this homogeneous equation using $\frac{y}{x} = v$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can the following differential equation be solve?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$$

I divide the numerator and denominator by $x$ of $\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}= \dfrac{1-y/x}{1+y/x}$

If $y=vx$

I substitute  $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dv}{dx} x+v$

$\dfrac{dv}{dx}x+v = \dfrac{1-v}{1+v}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dx}x = \dfrac{1-v}{1+v}-v$

$\dfrac{dv}{dx}x = \dfrac{1-2v-v^2}{1+v}$

I solved this differential equation and got the wrong answer. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you divide the numerator and denominator by $x$ you get

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y}{x}}.$$

This suggests we make the substitution $v = \frac{y}{x}$. Then $v' = \frac{1}{x}y' - \frac{1}{x^2}y$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: _Yes, thanks._'code'.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Replace $y$ by $v x$; express $y'$ and replace everywhere in the equation. You will see that the problem becomes simple if you write the differential equation as $dx/dv =???$ .